# Sheet to graph, need of a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have this data in a spreadsheet (picture 1) et I'd like to know how can I make it look like the data graph in the second picture. I tried to insert a chart but I can't find a way to make it look similar to the picture 2 graph. Do I need a macro to do this ?
Thanks.

[image: excel_1]
[image: excel_2]

Answer (score 1):

No need for a macro.

- add an extra helper column with values `1, 2, 3 ... n` (even for the empty rows)
- insert an empty **Scatter** chart type
- via `Select Data` > `Add`, add 4 series, each column in turn will be `Series X values`, while the new helper column will be always the `Series Y values`
- adjust formatting as needed, e.g.:

  - for the big blue separators you will need to change vertical axis major units to 5 and then format major gridlines line style to be very thick and color to be solid blue with transparency, then delete the vertical axis itself to hide the helper numbers
  - `format data series` > `marker options` to change the arbitrary shapes to circles - but you might want to preserve the different shapes and use a transparent color to make the overlapping values visible

There is no way to automatically make the shapes move a little to avoid overlapping, but you can create 4 helper columns instead of 1 with slighly different values (`1.1, 2.1, 3.1 ... n+ 0.1` and so on) to work around this limitation.